# html tag nobr is not working in outlook mail trying to avoid line break

Tags: html, email, outlook

nobr is not working in Outlook mail.`<nobr>`i am using in perl script to avoid line break.But the same is not working in outlook mail.

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you share a bit of code? what have you tried? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I have used this code under table - <tr><b><td colspan ='4' style='font-family:arial;font-size:22px;text-align:center;'><nobr>Research/Modelware Production Stability- Alerts KPI</nobr></td></b></tr>.Problem is if we adjust the screen then those words coming into next line,which i dont want.It Should be in single line even if we adjust the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
&nbsp;
```

Is well supported, so you could use:

```
<tr><b><td colspan ='4' style='font-family:arial;font-size:22px;text-align:center;'><nobr>Research/Modelware&nbsp;Production&nbsp;Stability&#8209;&nbsp;Alerts KPI</nobr></td></b></tr>
```

I also added a non-breaking hyphen:

```
&#8209;
```

Hopefully that will help!